# Using a switch statement to determine GPA result

Tags: java

This is the code to determine a GPA from the command line. At the moment, the code is incorrect. I'm hoping to see the corrected code.

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args)  {
    double gpa = Integer.parseInt(args [0]);
    switch(gpa)) {
      case (gpa>3.5) :           System.out.println("First class Hons"); break;
      case (3.49=> gpa => 3.0):  System.out.println("upper Second class Hons"); break;
      case (2.99=> gpa >= 2.5):  System.out.println("Lower Second class Hons"); break;
      case (2.99=> gpa >= 2.0):  System.out.println("Pass"); break;
      case (2.0 => gpa):         System.out.println("Fail"); break;
      default:                   System.out.println("Invalied gpa");
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: You cannot use a switch statement to compare a double. Use if-else statements instead.

Comment: with out double, how create that code

Comment: @Deshika22: Why are you so eager to use a `switch` statement? It's simply not appropriate for ranges.

Comment: Upvoted because it's a problem that I can see others facing, but it's not in an ideal format. If you could tell us more about why you're *trying* to use a `switch` statement, that would be useful.

Answer (score 9):

Switch/case statements don't work like that. They're not conditions - they're specific *cases*. (And, as pointed out by others, you can't switch on `double` values anyway.) You just want a lot of `if`/`else` statements:

```
String grade;
if (gpa >= 3.5) {
    grade = "First class Hons";
} else if (gpa >= 3.0) {
    grade = "Upper second class Hons";
} else if (gpa >= 2.5) {
    grade = "Lower second class Hons";
} else if (gpa >= 2.0) {
    grade = "Pass";
} else {
    grade = "Fail";
}
System.out.println(grade);
```

It's important to note that I'm only using *one* condition for each check here - even if your syntax for switch/case worked, and even if you'd changed `=>` to `>=` in each case, you'd still have invalid cases such as 3.495 which didn't fall into any buckets. It also means that you only need to specify each boundary once.

Now, when you've got it compiling it's still going to fail if you enter "3.5" as input, because of this line:

```
double gpa = Integer.parseInt(args [0]);
```

You actually want

```
double gpa = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
```

... otherwise you'll only parse *integer* input.

You might also want to consider using `BigDecimal` instead of `double` here - for this specific case it may not matter, but if you're really interested in maintaining the exact decimal digits, `BigDecimal` is more appropriate.

Comment: @Deshika22: You can't. It just doesn't work for you here. (Heck, you can't even use `switch` with a `double`, but even if you could, you couldn't represent the ranges involved.) Just give up on using `switch` here.

Comment: @Deshika22 - If you really want to use a switch for some reason, convert to an int (round to nearest .5 increment, multiply by 10 then convert to an int: e.g. 3.79 -> 4.0 -> 40; then use integral cases) or use a language that allows more in a case statement, like [Go](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: you can't easily use `switch` here. Use a series of `if` statements instead.

Answer (score 2):

Java clearly states:

> A switch works with the byte, short, char, and int primitive data
>   types. It also works with enumerated types (discussed in Enum Types),
>   the String class, and a few special classes  that wrap certain
>   primitive types: Character, Byte, Short, and Integer (discussed in
>   Numbers  and String).

More details on switch along with example can be seen at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

So as suggested by others if-else is the way to go.

Comment: It's interesting that it doesn't work with `long`s... didn't know that.

Comment: @RaduMurzea: Reason for that might be that writes and reads to long are not atomic. Just a guess.

Comment: This is really interesting. I've tried it with long and it says `error: possible loss of precision. required: int, found: long`. I want to investigate this further...

Answer (score 2):

You could use a switch statement if you REALLY want, by using enums to represent the different grades:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double gpa = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
        Grade grade = Grade.getGradeFromGPA(gpa);

        switch (grade) {
            case FIRST_CLASS:   System.out.println("First class Hons"); break;
            case TWO_ONE:       System.out.println("upper Second class Hons"); break;
            case TWO_TWO:       System.out.println("Lower Second class Hons"); break;
            case PASS:          System.out.println("Pass"); break;
            case FAIL:          System.out.println("Fail"); break;
            default:            System.out.println("Invalied gpa");
        }
    }

    private enum Grade {
        FIRST_CLASS(3.5, 4),
        TWO_ONE(3, 3.49),
        TWO_TWO(2.5, 2.99),
        PASS(2.49, 2),
        FAIL(0, 1.99);

        private final double minGPA;
        private final double maxGPA;

        Grade(final double minGPA, final double maxGPA) {
            this.minGPA = minGPA;
            this.maxGPA = maxGPA;
        }

        static Grade getGradeFromGPA(double gpa) {
            for (Grade grade : Grade.values()) {
                if (grade.maxGPA >= gpa && grade.minGPA <= gpa) {
                    return grade;
                }
            }
            //invalid GPA
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Notes:

- I've corrected Integer.parseInt to Double.parseDouble
- I have left the logic the way it was in your question, but it does leave a doubt around what happens with inputs like 3.499 - this will return an invalid grade, as it slips between the max of TWO_ONE and the min of FIRST_CLASS

If you really used an enum, you probably wouldn't use a switch to print out the grade.  You'd be better off having a String representing the description of the grade and printing that, i.e.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double gpa = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
    Grade grade = Grade.getGradeFromGPA(gpa);

    if (grade != null) {
        System.out.println(grade.description);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalied gpa");
    }
}

private enum Grade {
    FIRST_CLASS(3.5, 4, "First class Hons"),
    TWO_ONE(3, 3.49, "upper Second class Hons"),
    TWO_TWO(2.5, 2.99, "Lower Second class Hons"),
    PASS(2.49, 2, "Pass"),
    FAIL(0, 1.99, "Fail");

    private final double minGPA;
    private final double maxGPA;
    private final String description;

    // remaining code omitted for brevity
}
```

The moral of this story is that you shouldn't let your programming hammer (in this case, the switch statement) drive your design.  Your code should reflect the problem you're trying to solve, you shouldn't be forcing your problem into the shape of your code.